# how to integrate react-select with mobx?

Tags: mobx, react-select

I'm working with react-select, to add a multi-select control in my web-app. http://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/
I'm looking for a good example to inject mobx observables into the control.
The first challenge I have is initialising the options in an async way (options are fetched from server, but after that I want regular filtering to apply, no need for async-options).
Any good examples out there?

```
import Select from 'react-select';

<Select
      multi
      disabled={this.state.disabled}
      value={this.state.value}
      placeholder="Select your favourite(s)"
      options={this.state.options}
      onChange={this.handleSelectChange}
    />
```

Answer (score 8):

As noted in MobX documentation, due to limitations in ES5, `ObservableArray` still has some [quirks](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/array.html). `react-select` is one of those libraries that don't work with `ObservableArray` out of the box. There are 2 ways to solve this.

#### Method 1

you already have an observable array with `label` and `value`

```
@observable myOptions = [
  {label: 'foo', value: 123},
  {label: 'bar', value: 345}
]
```

then you can use the `ObservableArray`'s `.peek()` method to return a regular array for read-only purposes

```
<Select
  options={this.myOptions.peek()}
  onChange={this.handleSelectChange}
/>
```

#### Method 2

You have the observable array in some other format, returned from server. This is a more common case, actually.

```
@observable peopleData = [
  {name: 'foo', _id: 123, address: 'fooville'},
  {name: 'bar', _id: 345, address: 'barville'}
]
```

in this case, you can create a `@computed` value, which also returns a plain array:

```
@computed get peopleOptions() {
  return this.peopleData.map(x => ({ label: x.name, value: x._id })
}
```

and connect the Select component to the computed value, which will auto-update each time new data from server are fetched.

```
<Select
  options={this.peopleOptions}
  onChange={this.handleSelectChange}
/>
```

in both cases, `this.handleSelectChange` should just update the original data.

Comment: This should've been accepted as the answer. Thank you Tomas for the tips!

Comment: Method 2 is what I ended up using, but I haven't found a clear way to handle `value` of that Select if it's also kept in the store somewhere... Typically you'll just have the `id`, and there's no easy way to find the option object you create in `peopleOptions` to bind to the value